# Firestore cloud functions.https.onRequest Request.url.split("/") not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I try to make an https function with request URL splitting but it keeps gave me undefine like this
[log console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q49mZ.png)

from this code

```
//functions/index.js
exports.showEvent = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const params = req.url.split("/");
    const Id = params[2];
    res.status(200).send(Id);
    console.log(Id)
});
```

And this is my url that gave me the undefine for the photo
`https://us-central1-(myproject).cloudfunctions.net/showEvent/Meann`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do `console.log(req.url)` you will see that you get `/Meann`

So you need to modify your code along these lines:

```
exports.showEvent = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    const params = req.url.split("/");
    const id = params[1];
    console.log(id)
    res.status(200).send(id);
});
```